# Tiebreaker in proc fedsql

Tags: sql

How do I tiebreak between rows in PROC FEDSQL, based on whether they have the max of Variable A, and if they have the same value of Variable A, then based on whether they have the max of Variable B?

e.g. for the input

```
GROUP ID Var_A Var_B
A     1  2     1
A     2  4     2
B     3  1     3
B     4  1     2
C     5  1     2
C     6  2     1
```

I would want the output to be

```
GROUP ID 
A     2  
B     3  
C     6
```

Comment: Can you add the rows ('C',5,1,2) and ('C',6,2,1) to your sample data, and adjust the expected result - if needed? https://dbfiddle.uk/oU6siNGR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a windowed Max() is what you need here:

```
with g as (
  select *, 
    Max(var_a) over(partition by "GROUP") MaxA, 
    Max(var_b) over(partition by "GROUP") MaxB
  from t
)
select "GROUP", Id
from g
where var_A = MaxA and var_B = MaxB;
```

Answer (score 1):

**ANSI SQL solution** (utilizing the optional features T611, Elementary OLAP operations and F591, Derived tables):

Order each group by var_a desc, var_b desc, and pick the first row:

```
select "group", id
from
(
  select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by "group" order by var_a desc, var_b desc) rowno
  from t
) dt
where rowno = 1
```

**Postgresql special solution**, using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
select distinct on ("group") "group", id
from t
order by "group", var_a desc, var_b desc
```